# PHP add html break after every 10th mysql result

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having a trouble with my code. What I am trying to achieve:

I have a database table called "matches", containing info about football fixtures. For now i have around 100 matches in this table, but soon to be 500+, so to not to blow my viewers minds, i want my code to perform a line break (or maybe a new table row, thats not important now, just some HTML tag) after every 10th result is shown(because every week there are 10 matches)

Here is my PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY matchid ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($Connection, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($sql));
$fixtures='';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query )) { 
    $fixturetime = $row["time"];
    $fixturetime2 = $row["time"];
    $fixtureid = $row["matchid"];
    $fixtureround = $row["round"];
    $hometeamid = $row["hometeamid"];
    $awayteamid = $row["awayteamid"];
    $fixturetime = strtotime( $fixturetime );
    $fixturetime = date( 'd.m.Y', $fixturetime );
    $fixturetime2 = strtotime( $fixturetime2 );
    $fixturetime2 = date( 'H:i', $fixturetime2 );

    $fixtures.='<tr><td><strong>' .$hometeamname. '</strong> v. <strong>' .$awayteamname. '</strong></td><td>' .$fixturetime. '</td><td>' .$fixturetime2. '</td><td style="text-align: right;">' .$fixtureid. '</td><td>' .$i. '</td></tr>';
}
```

And here is HTML output:

```
<table>
    <?php echo $fixtures; ?>
</table>
```

I have tried some methods shown on stackoverflow, but I was not able to implement them properly to my solution. Because I am kinda new to PHP I am asking for specific solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY matchid ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($Connection, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($sql));
$fixtures = '';
$i = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $fixturetime = $row["time"];
    $fixturetime2 = $row["time"];
    $fixtureid = $row["matchid"];
    $fixtureround = $row["round"];
    $hometeamid = $row["hometeamid"];
    $awayteamid = $row["awayteamid"];
    $fixturetime = strtotime($fixturetime);
    $fixturetime = date('d.m.Y', $fixturetime);
    $fixturetime2 = strtotime($fixturetime2);
    $fixturetime2 = date('H:i', $fixturetime2);

    $fixtures .= '<tr><td><strong>' . $hometeamname . '</strong> v. <strong>' . $awayteamname . '</strong></td><td>' . $fixturetime . '</td><td>' . $fixturetime2 . '</td><td style="text-align: right;">' . $fixtureid . '</td><td>' . $i . '</td></tr>';

    if(!($i % 10)){
        $fixtures .= '<!-- break -->';
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: With `$i=0` you'll get a break after the first row. Suggest setting `$i=1` to start with instead.

Comment: Oh, my bad... fixed ;)

Comment: I beat you by a minute. ;-p

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using mod or the % sign, this returns the remainder from division ( so the remainder of n / 10 will be 0 every 10 rows ).

So you'll want to have a counter

```
$count = 1;
while( $row = ..... ){
    if( $count % 10 == 0 ){
     //do line break;
   }


   ++$count;
}
```

php Documention on mod
http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php

you might have to play with this a bit but that's the basics.

Comment: This is the right way to do it :) But if you're new to PHP then see other answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the simplest thing I can think of.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY matchid ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($Connection, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($sql));
$fixtures='';
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query )) { 
$counter++;
$fixturetime = $row["time"];
$fixturetime2 = $row["time"];
$fixtureid = $row["matchid"];
$fixtureround = $row["round"];
$hometeamid = $row["hometeamid"];
$awayteamid = $row["awayteamid"];
$fixturetime = strtotime( $fixturetime );
$fixturetime = date( 'd.m.Y', $fixturetime );
$fixturetime2 = strtotime( $fixturetime2 );
$fixturetime2 = date( 'H:i', $fixturetime2 );

$fixtures.='<tr><td><strong>' .$hometeamname. '</strong> v. <strong>' .$awayteamname. '</strong></td><td>' .$fixturetime. '</td><td>' .$fixturetime2. '</td><td style="text-align: right;">' .$fixtureid. '</td><td>' .$i. '</td></tr>';

if (($counter % 10) == 0){ $fixtures .= '<br>'; }
}
```

This will add 1 to the counter each time that the while iterates. The if statement will check to see whether there's a remainder after checking $counter against 10. If there is one it'll keep running without a line break. If there Is no remainder, meaning it's multiple of 10, it will append a 
 to the end.

Hope this is what you want!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to count each row. Using a new variable `$i` starting at `0`, this variable will get increased by one at every loop. Then check if that variable is above 10. If it is add more html to the `$fixtures` string that creates a "blank" row.

If a blank row is found also reset the `$i` variable back to `0`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY matchid ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($Connection, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($sql));
$fixtures='';
$i = 0; // <-- New variable

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query )) { 

    $fixturetime = $row["time"];
    $fixturetime2 = $row["time"];
    $fixtureid = $row["matchid"];
    $fixtureround = $row["round"];
    $hometeamid = $row["hometeamid"];
    $awayteamid = $row["awayteamid"];
    $fixturetime = strtotime( $fixturetime );
    $fixturetime = date( 'd.m.Y', $fixturetime );
    $fixturetime2 = strtotime( $fixturetime2 );
    $fixturetime2 = date( 'H:i', $fixturetime2 );

    $fixtures.='<tr><td><strong>' .$hometeamname. '</strong> v. <strong>' .$awayteamname. '</strong></td><td>' .$fixturetime. '</td><td>' .$fixturetime2. '</td><td style="text-align: right;">' .$fixtureid. '</td><td>' .$i. '</td></tr>';

    $i ++; // <-- add one

    if ($i > 10) { // <-- If larger than 10 then do this statement

        $fixtures.='<tr><td colspan=4>BREAK</td></tr>';
        $i = 0; // <-- Oh and reset $i
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look up pagination solutions that use `OFFSET` with the `LIMIT` clause.  Outside of that though, you can actually store your results in groups of 10 and then apply output logic as you loop through the groups:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY matchid ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($Connection, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($sql));
$fixtures = array(); // Each element will be an array of fixtures
$fixturesPerGroup = 10; // How many fixtures per group
$fixtureCount = 0; // Counter during the while loop iterating
$fixtureGroup = 0; // Which group to put the fixtures into
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query )) { 
    $fixturetime = $row["time"];
    $fixturetime2 = $row["time"];
    $fixtureid = $row["matchid"];
    $fixtureround = $row["round"];
    $hometeamid = $row["hometeamid"];
    $awayteamid = $row["awayteamid"];
    $fixturetime = strtotime( $fixturetime );
    $fixturetime = date( 'd.m.Y', $fixturetime );
    $fixturetime2 = strtotime( $fixturetime2 );
    $fixturetime2 = date( 'H:i', $fixturetime2 );

    $fixtures[$fixtureGroup][] ='<tr><td><strong>' .$hometeamname. '</strong> v. <strong>' .$awayteamname. '</strong></td><td>' .$fixturetime. '</td><td>' .$fixturetime2. '</td><td style="text-align: right;">' .$fixtureid. '</td><td>' .$i. '</td></tr>';

    $fixtureCount++;
    // Once we reach the fixturesPerGroup count, go to the next group
    if (($fixtureCount % $fixturesPerGroup) == 0) {
        $fixtureGroup++;
    }
}
```

Then you can loop through the groups:

```
<table>
<?php 
foreach ($fixtures as $fixturesInGroup) {
    // Do logic here for displaying each group
    echo implode('<br />', $fixturesInGroup);
}
?>
</table>
```