# Want to break the loop after 10 rows to show a banner and than continue the loop were it stopt using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have seen some solutions already for tables but for some reason the break also duplicated which only need to be shown once

i have the following code:

```
<?php
    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ echo "<div class='col-lg-12'><div class='panel panel-default'>".$result['brand']." ".$result['modelyear']." ".$result['type']."<img  src='".$result['link_image']." heigth:'50px' class='img-responsive'></div></div>";}
?>
```

I would like to try to break it after 10 rows and than show a div with a banner in it.

i tried the following [PHP add html break after every 10th mysql result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663919/php-add-html-break-after-every-10th-mysql-result)

however the banner also multiplies it self.

and yes i am a noob

Regards

Bas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a variable that increment every time the loop execute. After the condition met you can display your div and end the loop. Something like this.

```
$i=0;
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
    if($i % 10 == 0){
        echo "<div>Banner Div</div>";
    } else { 
        echo "<div>Normal Div</div>";
    }     
    $i++; 
}
```

Comment: break should be continue, else the while will exit

Comment: i think the OP said that he wands to exit the loop after 10 rows, maybe i haven't get the question right

Comment: i think the OP just want to add a banner after as the 10th entry.

Comment: @Rafael thank you! but after the banner it need to continue again with the loop were it left off.

Comment: @BasMienis without the break in the if it will continue

Comment: @BasMienis i have add the modulus operator. After 10 rows the special div sould show

Comment: i have removed the break but after the first ten it is looping the banner

Comment: @BasMienis refresh make sure to get the updated answer

Comment: @BasMienis be safe ;)